# Fastest way to Requests many image contents

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt6

From newsapi I am trying to get request of all images and set it as a icon to all my listWidget although my code does work I was wondering if there's a faster way to request 100+ images and set it as a icon to my QlistWidget

Comment: Be aware that the above code is destined to crash sooner or later (if it doesn't right now, it's just for "luck", but it will probably create issues anyway, such as inconsistent behavior and drawing artifacts): widgets are not thread safe, and cannot created/accessed from external threads. Consider looking into [QNetworkAccessManager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html), which is asynchronous by nature and allows performing parallel transfers.

Comment: Hello, the code does work. Yes I have looked into QNetworkAcessManager but I can't seem to find a good example that can help me implement it for my program. I have looked into asynchronous requests as well but still I am not getting how to implement it

Comment: The fact that it works in your case is irrelevant, because, as already said, it's just for **luck**: a combination of aspects that include OS threading management, CPU speed, available resources, etc. In Qt (as in almost any UI toolkit) UI elements are **NOT** thread safe (the Qt documentation clearly [remarks this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/threads-qobject.html#qobject-reentrancy), and thousands of posts even here on StackOverflow demonstrate this), and if you do it it's at your own risk.

Comment: Alright understood. The problem that threading had fixed was the UI not loading till all of the images had been requested and set those picture to QlistWidget which took about 4-5 seconds of the program not opening. How would I fix that without threading? Also you said instead of request use QNetworkAccessManager can you please give me a brief example on how I can request images using (QNetworkAccessManager) and set it to my QlistWidget

Comment: I never said that you shouldn't use threading, but that you cannot directly access UI elements from external threads. The only way to achieve this in Qt is by using custom signals in a QThread subclass (or in a QObject moved to a QThread, depending on the needs). Sorry, but I cannot give you an example, as this is not the scope of StackOverflow. I'm aware that using QNetworkAccessManager might seem difficult at first, so I'd suggest you to get acquainted to it by creating small test scripts in order to understand how it works. And, obviously, carefully and patiently study the documentation.

Comment: If you can't give me an example, maybe you can let me know good resources to look at cause every resource I looked it's C++ examples and I am not familiar with c++